# repeat string in R

Tags: r, string, repeat

I would like to repeat a string of number or characters.
Let's suppose I have this two vectors.

```
vector1<-c(1,2,3)
vector2<-c(XZK,V3Z,KG4)
```

I would like to use a function that replicate each vector three times without entering everything manually like below.

```
c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
c("XZK","XZK","XZK","V3Z","V3Z","V3Z","KG4","KG4","KG4")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rep` with `each`

```
f1 <- function(vec, n) rep(vec, each = n)
f1(vector1, 3)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

f1(vector2, 3)
#[1] "XZK" "XZK" "XZK" "V3Z" "V3Z" "V3Z" "KG4" "KG4" "KG4"
```

#### data

```
vector2 <- c('XZK','V3Z','KG4')
```